# Does pusher support bi-directional communication? If yes then how to implement it in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, pusher, pusher-js

I can see only one way communication in pusher docs i.e., from server to client. How to do it from client to server with node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Pusher Channels does not support bidirectional transport. If you need to send data from your client to your server you will have to use another solution such as a POST request.

Channels does offer [webhooks](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/webhooks) which can be triggered by certain events in the application and could be consumed by your server if they fit your requirements. However, webhooks are designed to keep you informed of certain events within your application rather than as a means of communication between client and server.